# Convert matlab.graphics.primitive.text to string

Tags: string, matlab, text, matlab-figure

I can object `nameX` that have type `1x1 Text` and want set this obj to my figure xlabel.

When i try execute `xlabel(nameX);` i get and error `Error using xlabel Not enough input arguments.`. I understand that i shoud convert to string this item but i do not know how to make it.

P.S.
Of couse i try get all fields using command:`fieldnames(nameX)`
Resut:

```
41×1 cell array

    {'Color'              }
    {'Position'           }
    {'String'             }
    {'Interpreter'        }
    {'Extent'             }
    {'Rotation'           }
    {'FontName'           }
    {'FontUnits'          }
    {'FontSize'           }
    {'FontAngle'          }
    {'FontWeight'         }
    {'HorizontalAlignment'}
    {'VerticalAlignment'  }
    {'EdgeColor'          }
    {'LineStyle'          }
    {'LineWidth'          }
    {'BackgroundColor'    }
    {'Margin'             }
    {'Editing'            }
    {'Clipping'           }
    {'FontSmoothing'      }
    {'Interactions'       }
    {'Units'              }
    {'Children'           }
    {'Parent'             }
    {'Visible'            }
    {'HandleVisibility'   }
    {'ButtonDownFcn'      }
    {'ContextMenu'        }
    {'BusyAction'         }
    {'BeingDeleted'       }
    {'Interruptible'      }
    {'CreateFcn'          }
    {'DeleteFcn'          }
    {'Type'               }
    {'Tag'                }
    {'UserData'           }
    {'Selected'           }
    {'SelectionHighlight' }
    {'HitTest'            }
    {'PickableParts'      }
```

After i try to get prop: `nameX.String` and get an error:
`Invalid or deleted object.`
What i do wrong?

Comment: i would really like to help you but  how the question is worded is fairly incomprehensible. xlabel takes a string as input argument, you should provide that. the second error you get is usually because you closed the figure so matlab cannot refer to it anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we  have a graphic object containing texts:

```
fh=figure()
text(1,1,'MyTEXT')
```

You could get the string back from the graph handle:

```
myTxtStr=fh.Children(1).Children(1).String
```

That text string can be used in old or new graphs as the x-label

```
xlabel(fh.Children(1),myTxtStr)
fhnew=figure()
ax=axes();
xlabel(ax,myTxtStr)
```

Just notice that the index for each of the Children() call could vary depends on the actual grpah.